# How to remove multiple lines per occurrence in a file?

Tags: grep, text-processing, sed

Say I have this 857835 line file, containing stuff like this:

```
a1
rubbish1
rubbish2
rubbish3
rubbish4
a1
rubbish5
rubbish6
rubbish7
rubbish8
```

And I wish to remove all occurences of `a1` and the next line (`rubbish1` and `rubbish5` in this example).  How do I do it?

I've tried `grep 'a1' -v -A1` to no avail, and my sed skillz are not really great :}

My Google-fu has not been able to help me this time, someone please help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -e '/^a1$/,+1d' "filename"
```

This means from /^a1$/ to the next line, delete

The ^ and $ ensure you match the whole line, so a hidden a1 will not be matched.

Comment: You might want `^` and `$` in that match, to force matching whole lines.

Comment: @Jander: Sure, corrected

Answer (score 12):

The following will work on non-GNU `sed` (the `,+1` address syntax is a GNU extension):

```
sed -e '/^a1$/,/^/d' my_file >my_filtered_file
```

"Starting at a line that reads exactly 'a1', and ending at the next line for which the beginning of the line exists (i.e. the next line), delete."

It's much less extensible than @asoundmove's answer, though, as deleting a different number of lines would take an entirely different script.